# Android : Providing auto autosuggestion in android places Api?

Tags: android, google-maps, search, autocomplete

I am very new to android Google maps i write the following program for displaying the auto sugesstion in the android when i am type the text in the Autocomplete text box it is going the input to the url but the out put is not showing in the program .please see once and let me know where i am doing the mistake.

```
   ExampleApp.java
package com.example.exampleapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater.Filter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExampleApp extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
        autoCompView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }
    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    private static final String API_KEY = "";
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                 //   filterResults.values = resultList;
                  //  filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
                ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
                    sb.append("?sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
                    sb.append("&components=country:uk");
                    sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

                    URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

                    // Load the results into a StringBuilder
                    int read;
                    char[] buff = new char[1024];
                    while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                        jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                   // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
                    return resultList;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
                    return resultList;
                } finally {
                    if (conn != null) {
                        conn.disconnect();
                    }
                }

                try {
                    // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
                    JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

                    // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
                    resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
                    for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                   // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
                }

                return resultList;
            }
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onLoadClass(Class arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }};
        return (android.widget.Filter) filter;
    }
}

FilterResults.java

package com.example.exampleapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FilterResults {

    protected ArrayList<String> values;
    protected int count;

}


i write the above code but the application closed .please see once and let me know where i am doing mistake in the above code ?
Thanks in Advance..........
```

Comment: please help me how can i achive this ?

Comment: hey this is my.problem is not solve till...getting error ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the Code Snippet Which i have Used when i have similar problem. i give you one suggestion that D'nt put your whole code in only single java file. Make the separate methods/class for each different task you are using in your code. it will help you easier to trace it.

here is my PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.java File.

```
package com.inukshk.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

import com.inukshk.CreateInukshk.CreateInukshk;

public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements
        Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.

                    resultList = CreateInukshk.autocomplete(constraint
                            .toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

here is What you have to do  inside OnCreate() of your activity.

```
autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editloc);
        autoCompView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item));
```

here are the static Strings i have used in app.

```
private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";
    private static final String API_KEY = "YOUR API KEY";
```

and Finally here is the Method that you will use in Adapter.

```
public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {

        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE
                    + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
            // sb.append("&components=country:uk");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                        "description"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }
```

**EDITED :**

i guess you have specified the list_item.xml as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

try it out. Hope it will helps you.

**UPDATE :**

```
You have to manually attach the debugger while the emulator says "Waiting for debugger to attach". In Netbean's menu bar, click "Debug", then "Attach Debugger...". You have to select your package from the "Process" drop down list, and then click "Attach". That should do it.
This works in Netbeans 7 anyway.
```

or you can try out below thing also.

```
You have two choices: connect a debugger, or kill the process.

Looking at your logcat, you have at least two different desktop applications that are trying to connect to each application process, which is where the "Ignoring second debugger" messages are coming from.

This would happen if you were, say, running Eclipse with the ADT plugin, and the stand-alone DDMS at the same time. I don't know what you're running or what the netbeans plugin does, but I would start by figuring out if you have two different things fighting for control.
```

**EDITED:** `HOW TO GET TEXT OF AutoCompleteTextView`

just write this code snippet.

```
autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                YOURTEXT = autoCompView.getText().toString();
                //new AsyncGetAutoPlace().execute(autoCompView.getText()
                //      .toString().trim());
            }
        });
```

Comment: FilterResults  how can i invoke this ?

Comment: please give sugesstion so that i can forward

Comment: you have to import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

Comment: "FilterResults how can i invoke this ?" sory but i didn't get it. you are facing any problem while importing them?

Comment: just now i updated my code please see once my program closed when i am run the app?

Comment: "API_KEY="" " you are sure you have specified right APIkey here?

Comment: https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:1050266420752:access from this i got the key ?

Comment: filterResults.values = resultList; filterResults.count = resultList.size();  why you have put this code in comment?

Comment: "run it get closed?" meanse you are getting force close?

Comment: can you post your logcate error? it will be easy for us to give you suggestion.

Comment: 11-02 12:05:29.862: E/Trace(1075): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: 11-02 12:05:30.102: W/ActivityThread(1075): Application com.example.exampleapp is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...

Comment: see my log cat and let me know my mistake ?

Comment: in my program i dont put any breakpoints and debug mode when i run this it get close ?

Comment: you can restart your avd and eclipse. and try it out again.

Comment: just now i send plase see once

Comment: please give me the reply so that i can farward

Comment: Hi thanks for ur valuebale help i have small dout if u dont mind

Comment: https://maps.google.co.in/ in this the places search open in one way but in our program looks some what different ?

Comment: yes, it may happen they have use different pattern for searching. but i think you will definitely find each and every position in the World from the above code. now if you are satisfiable with answer.then accept it so that other Users can also not it as Acceptable solution.

Comment: hey can u sugesst how can i get Autocompletetexview text?

Comment: Edited my answer. please check it.

Comment: @Bhavesh I get null pointer exception when i declare 
autoCompView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item));
can you tell me the possible reasons?

Answer (score 0):

We have to add billing credentials first... so, create a project on google developer console and complete billing section.

Add The variables

```
//Autocomplete for location ----------------------------------------------
ArrayList<String> names;
String browserKey = "AIzaSyA.....................";
String url;
private static final String TAG_RESULT = "predictions";
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

Add this code in oncreate

```
    edtLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id
            .edt_location);
    edtLocation.setThreshold(1);


    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    edtLocation.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {

            if (s.toString().length() <= 6) {

                names = new ArrayList<String>();
                updateList(s.toString());


            }


        }
    });
```

Add this method in ur activity

```
  //Method to get location suggestion
public void updateList(String place) {
    String input = "";

    try {
        input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place, "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String output = "json";
    String parameter = input + "&types=(regions)&sensor=true&key="
            + browserKey;

    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"
            + output + "?" + parameter;


    Log.e("browsekey", browserKey);
    Log.e("URL-LOCation", url);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            System.out.println("keyresponse==>>" + response.toString());

            try {

                JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);

                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                    String description = c.getString("description");
                    Log.d("description", description);
                    names.add(description);
                }

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names) {
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position,
                                        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        return view;
                    }
                };
                edtLocation.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jsonObjReq, "jreq");
}
```

Add MyApplication class to call webservice

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static MyApplication mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getReqQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {

    getReqQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req) {

    getReqQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingReq(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
```

}